# When to drop "dass"

Tags: subordinate-clause

Under what circumstances can/do you drop "dass" in German? Is it similar to the usage of "that" in English. (The links below outline what I mean by that for those of you unfamiliar.)

Examples:

Sie hat gesagt, sie weiß es schon.

Er hat erklärt, dass er zu neuen Verhandlungen bereit ist.

Links:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296720/what-does-the-complementizer-that-accomplish-in-terms-of-style#comment666016_296720

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/307438/should-i-use-the-word-that-in-a-sentence-when-it-is-not-required

Also, note that the answer to the question pasted below only discusses how one would use formal language instead of the "dass." The examples above are (fairly?) colloquial so I don't think this question should be marked as a duplicate.

[When does one require "dass" and when can it be omitted?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9630/when-does-one-require-dass-and-when-can-it-be-omitted)

Comment: Note that it is not just omitted, the word order also is different.

Comment: *Sie hat gesagt, sie weiß es schon.* is sloppy speech. It's indirect speech so you should use *Konjunktiv I*: *Sie hat gesagt, sie wüsste es schon.* Same for the construction with *dass*.

Comment: @janka warum wüsste und nicht wisse?

Comment: Weil ich Wissen grundsätzlich anzweifle.

Comment: @janka Das macht *wüsste* auch nicht zu Konjunktiv 1 ;)

Comment: Man kann Kommentare nicht ewig editieren.

Comment: @Janka Der Kommentator sagte, man könne Kommentare nicht ewig editieren. Eigentlich ***wisse*** er schon, wie man indirekte Rede richtig formuliere. ***Wüsste*** er es nicht (doch er wisse es ja), zöge er ein kluges Buch dazu zu Rate oder richtete eine Frage an ein geeignetes Internet-Forum.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Bei dem Thema verweise ich immer wieder gern auf Daniel Scholtens Buch _Denksport Deutsch_ oder auf seine Belleslettres-Seiten _https://www.belleslettres.eu/index.php#konjunktiv_.

Answer (score 6):

You *cannot* omit *dass*, ever.

Your example shows two different constructions; the one with *dass* uses a subclause, and if you want this kind of subclause you *must* mark it with *dass*. For some verbs such as "sagen", you can use a subordinated main clause, which doesn't use *dass*, but as Carsten points out, that isn't just dropping the *dass*, it also involves using a different sentence pattern with a different word order.

You can only ever omit *dass* in parallel constructions with a coordination. For instance both, the following are correct:

> Sie hat gesagt, dass sie es schon weiss und dass ich sie nicht nerven soll.
>
> Sie hat gesagt, dass sie es schon weiss und ich sie nicht nerven soll.

However, this is a general property of coordinations: repeated elements in the same positions can be omitted; it has nothing to do with *dass* in particular.

Note that in English, the word *that* can sometimes be omitted when it's an object relative pronoun (and in older dialects it could be omitted even as a subject relative pronoun). This effect doesn't translate to German, since German uses *der*, *die*, *das* as relative pronouns and not *dass*, and they cannot be omitted.